# responsive word cloud with D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, word-cloud

I'm trying to implement a **responsive** word cloud with d3.js. I need also the ability to update/change the data.

There is a lot of examples based on the very good solution of [Jason Davies](https://www.jasondavies.com/wordcloud/). I'm trying to adjust a word cloud implementation [(found here)](https://julienrenaux.fr/2014/09/23/d3-js-responsive-word-cloud/) to meet my requirements.

This is my code.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/d3/d3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/d3-cloud/d3.layout.cloud.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="tags.js"></script>

<body>
    <div id="wordcloud">
        <div id="vis"></div>
    </div>

<script>

var w = window.innerWidth,  h = window.innerHeight;

var fontSize;

var layout = d3.layout.cloud()
        .timeInterval(Infinity)
        .size([w, h])
        .fontSize(function(d) {
            return fontSize(+d.value);
        })
        .text(function(d) {
            return d.key;
        })
        .on("end", draw);

var svg = d3.select("#vis").append("svg")
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", h);

var vis = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + [w >> 1, h >> 1] + ")");

update();

if(window.attachEvent) {
    window.attachEvent('onresize', update);
}
else if(window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener('resize', update);
}

function draw(data, bounds) {
    var w = window.innerWidth,
        h = window.innerHeight;

//   ***          
        svg.remove();
        svg = d3.select("#vis").append("svg")
                .attr("width", w)
                .attr("height", h);

        vis = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + [w >> 1, h >> 1] + ")");
//   ***   

    svg.attr("width", w).attr("height", h);

    scale = bounds ? Math.min(
            w / Math.abs(bounds[1].x - w / 2),
            w / Math.abs(bounds[0].x - w / 2),
            h / Math.abs(bounds[1].y - h / 2),
            h / Math.abs(bounds[0].y - h / 2)) / 2 : 1;

    var text = vis.selectAll("text")
            .data(data, function(d) {
                return d.text.toLowerCase();
            });
    text.transition()
            .duration(1000)
            .attr("transform", function(d) {
                return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")rotate(" + d.rotate + ")";
            })
            .style("font-size", function(d) {
                return d.size + "px";
            });
    text.enter().append("text")
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .attr("transform", function(d) {
                return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")rotate(" + d.rotate + ")";
            })
            .style("font-size", function(d) {
                return d.size + "px";
            })
            .style("opacity", 1e-6)
            .transition()
            .duration(1000)
            .style("opacity", 1);
    text.style("font-family", function(d) {
        return d.font;
    })
            .style("fill", function(d) {
                return fill(d.text.toLowerCase());
            })
            .text(function(d) {
                return d.text;
            });

    vis.transition().attr("transform", "translate(" + [w >> 1, h >> 1] + ")scale(" + scale + ")");
}

function update() {
    layout.font('impact').spiral('archimedean');
    fontSize = d3.scale['sqrt']().range([10, 100]);
    if (tags.length){
        fontSize.domain([+tags[tags.length - 1].value || 1, +tags[0].value]);
    }
    layout.stop().words(tags).start();
}

function changeWords(newTags) {
    tags = newTags;
    update();
}
</script>
```

This solution works fine for the whole window. But I want the word cloud to be displayed inside a div.

When I try to replace `var w = window.innerWidth, h = window.innerHeight;` with `var w = $('#wordcloud').innerWidth(), h = $('#wordcloud').innerHeight();` or something similar, it is not working.
In my real application, I want to use this solution, I have a deeply nested div inside other containers. The div doesn't have explicit width and height.

What am I missing here? 
Thanks for any help.

Comment: I remember working with Jason Davies' wordcloud and it was really difficult to make it responsive. I was however able to put it inside a container. Check my code and see if it can help you: http://wordcloud.adelriosantiago.com/

Comment: @adelriosantiago Thanks for replying. I see you are using `d3.min.js` and `d3.wordcloud.js`. But I can't find any javascript where the magic is happening. Could you post the relevant code part where you are dealing with the responsiveness?

Comment: In my example you can change the width and height of the wordcloud here: https://github.com/adelriosantiago/wikipedia-symptoms/blob/master/public/js/bigdoc.js#L8. Try playing with those values, the wordcloud that is contained by it should resize accordingly so you would only need to call that function when the `<div>` or wrapper resizes.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define some value regarding div dimensions, either inline style or css.
For example, full page div:

```
<div id="wordcloud" style="width:100%; height:100vh; display: block">
    <div id="vis"></div>
</div>
```

will work, otherwise if any of the width or height property is missing or equal 0, script will halt.